I have a list with strings in it: ["one"; "two"; "three"] - how do I print it in F#?
let stringList = ["one"; "two"; "three"]

How do I print stringList in F#?
let stringList = ["one", "two", "three"]

let function2() =
  for i in 2 .. 3 do
    printf " "
  printfn "i"
function2()

I was expecting: "one", "two", "three"

I recommend to first make sure your code has no syntax errors (use dotnet fsi or an IDE to check and correct the errors). Then check the documentation for loops and printf.

Welcome to SO! There are many problems with your code, the first probably being that you don't even access the items in your list. Also, there are more idiomatic ways of doing things in F#, for example List.iter (printfn "%s") myList. Also, the elements of an F# list are syntactically distinguished by a semicolon, not a comma.

Can you please explain why you are expecting "one", "two", "three" here? You're not referencing stringList anywhere, and the only things you're printing are two spaces and then the letter "i". Can you paste the code that you actually tried? As others said, this doesn't compile.

let l = ["one"; "two"; "three"]
printf "%A" l

FInd the docs about printing here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/plaintext-formatting

There are multiple ways to print lists in F#. The simplest way, as shown by citykid is as follows:
let l = ["one"; "two"; "three"]
printf "%A" l

Otherwise, you can also use a for loop with string interpolation like so:
let l = ["one"; "two"; "three"]
for s in l do
    printf $"{s}, "


the only slight advantage this has over the other method is that it'll work without adjustment for arrays/lists and can be modified quite simply to print multi-dimensional arrays neatly
